# Asynchronous foreach react-native

Tags: react-native, pouchdb

I'm creating a chat-app with react-native and pouchdb for mobile, then I've a server with socket.io and rethinkdb. In PouchDB I store all chats between users, while in the rethinkdb I store the "offline messages". For "offline messages" I mean the messages that have been sent to users that are not online (I check that in socket.io server).

Now I got a problem. When my user open the app I've an `async componentWillMount` like that:

```
async componentWillMount(){

    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
    this.setState({ token: value });

    var self = this;
    await axios.get(server + '/index.php/api/TokenController/isValid', {headers: {Authorization: this.state.token}}).then((res) => {
        var resJson = JSON.parse(res.data);
        self.setState({userid: resJson.info.id});
    });
    await axios.get(server + '/index.php/api/FriendsController/getList', {headers: {Authorization: this.state.token}}).then((res) => {
        var resJson = JSON.parse(res.data);
        this.setState({friends: resJson.friends});
    });

    this.setState({loading: false});

    this.socket.emit('register', {connection_id: this.state.userid});
    await this.socket.on('hasMessages', data => Promise.all(data).then(res => {
        this.setState({offlineMessages: res});
        this.state.offlineMessages.forEach((v) => {
            console.log(v) // it stops to first iteration
        })
    }));
}
```

So, the user signin, I check if the token isValid, and then I got the friends list. After that, I register my user to my websocket and I send an "hasMessage" if there are messages for my user 
(example:

```
{
    "from_id":  "76" ,
    "id":  "e5f76ad6-761c-4637-a118-321a844a9634" ,
    "messages": {
        "1546799624050":  "Ciao" ,
        "1546799630274":  "Hola" ,
        "1546799633100":  "Hello" 
    } ,
   "to_id":  "1"
}
```

Ok, there is something for my user. So the response of "hasMessage" is something like that.
Now I must do a two loops (one is about the data, and another about messages foreach data, I must create a message object for all messages). How can I do that? I'm using a Promise that works, but then the nested forEach stops at first iteration and when I reload my app I see in console the other iterations..some idea?

I'm not very good in async/await/Promise request, I'm just learning!

Comment: Fyi, `setState` calls are synchronous and pooled, `this.state.token` may not be the value you think it is later in this function.

Comment: Hi, thank you! However I know that.. but I need the token only in componentWillMount.. but how could I store the token in state and then access to it from another function?

Comment: You can store it in state for use elsewhere in the component, but in `componentWillMount` you shouldn't reference `this.state.token` as there's no guarantee it's been set yet, but instead you should just use the value you get back from `AsyncStorage` directly.  BTW, `componentWillMount` will be deprecated soon and isn't recommended for use.  I know you're using RN, but I believe the lifecycle functions are the same as for both react. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: Oh, so I should use `componentDidMount`. It is not a problem..But I've this code: `await this.socket.on('hasMessage', (data) => {
            this.setState({offlineMessages: data});
        });`
in the async componentDidMount(), after that I have a console.log(this.state), but offlineMessages is an empty array as at start.. why? 

Instead the this.state.token is a valid token, and also the userid is ok. Where am I wrong? I'm not understanding that :/

Comment: Have you logged `data` to ensure it is what you expect? `...this.socket.on("hasMessages", data => {console.log(data); return Promise.all(data);}).then(res => { ...` I'm on mobile so I may have missed some syntax but hopefully you get the idea.